# Filter object-array based on object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to use array.filter() to filter an object array on the object names.

I've tried using array.constructor.name unsuccessfully.

```
var temp = ({ 
en: {
    id: `${scope}.en`,
    defaultMessage: 'English',
  },
  es: {
    id: `${scope}.es`,
    defaultMessage: 'Spanish',
  },
  ar: {
    id: `${scope}.ar`,
    defaultMessage: 'Arabic',
  },
});

var selectedObj = temp.filter(msg => msg.constructor.name === 'en');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array.filter function only works on arrays.  The Temp variable is not an array, it's an object.  An array would be contained inside of square brackets []

It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do, but if your goal is to simply assign the "en" object to the selectedObj variable, then I believe the following will work:

```
var selectedObj = temp.en;
```

If you've got a variable that contains the string 'en', then maybe you could try:

```
var code = 'en';
var selectedObj = temp[code];
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. That worked for me! And also thank you for reminding me that the array.filter function only works on arrays and not objects.